# Apply a background to an repeated element doesn't work on IE

Tags: angularjs

Better than few words, here is the code which doesn't work on IE.

```
<div ng-repeat="favcolor in favcolors" class="favorite" alt="{{favcolor.name}}" title="{{favcolor.name}}" style="background:#{{favcolor.hexa}}">{{favcolor.hexa}}</div>
```

The css :

```
.favorite{
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Everything is ok on other browsers, but on IE my boxes doesn't have any background color. When I replace {{favcolor.hexa}} with some hexa, it works fine...

Thx.

Comment: Which IE are you having the problem in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use ng-style.

```
<div ng-style="{ 'background' : '#' + favcolor.hexa }" ... >
```

Comment: Nice ! it works. I've tried this solution but i've forgotten the + operand :)
Thx for your help !